# Small Basic Variables in Arrays?

Tags: smallbasic

In my hangman program, I'm trying to use an array to detect if a letter has been pressed before, and therefore cannot be pressed again.

In my attempt to do this, I have tried using:

```
If targetarray[LastLetter] = 1 Then
```

Where 'LastLetter' is my variable.

In another section of my code I also have the arrays stored as such:

```
 Sub LetterArrays
  If GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "a" Then
    targetarray["a"] = 1
  ElseIf GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "b" Then
    targetarray["b"] = 1
```

And so on...

The sub that the initial code checking if the letter = 1 is inside a sub that is called when a letter is pressed (`GraphicsWindow.KeyDown`) and before my if clause, I used: `targetarray[LastLetter] = 1` as my way of setting the letter in the array to 1.

If this makes sense to you and you have a solution, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what it is you're asking, but if you are just looking to detect keypresses, then this code should do the trick for ya:

```
GraphicsWindow.KeyDown = KeyDown
GraphicsWindow.KeyUp = KeyUp

While 1 = 1
  Program.Delay(10)

  If Key["a"] Then
    TextWindow.WriteLine("Key 'a' was pressed")
  EndIf
EndWhile


Sub Keydown
  LastKeyDown = GraphicsWindow.LastKey
  Key[LastKeyDown] = "True"
EndSub

Sub KeyUp
  LastKeyUp = GraphicsWindow.LastKey
  Key[LastKeyUp] = "False"
EndSub
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you don't want the same key pressed twice. Here is how you could do this:

```
GraphicsWindow.KeyDown = KeyDown
i = 0

Sub KeyDown
    If Array.ContainsValue(keysPressed, GraphicsWindow.LastKey) Then
        ' key already pressed before
    Else
        ' key not pressed before
        i = i + i
        keysPressed[i] = GraphicsWindow.LastKey
        ' add code here
```